# 4GB Limit Android market

Tags: android, google-play

My application needs to download on the first run 50mb of data to work (and optional 500mb data), I thought about renting a server to host my files.. But I just read that Google increased the app limit in the market to 4GB:
Does that mean that you can host your data to the Android Market so that after your gets installed it downloads them from the Market?
Or does that mean that the max size of the .apk is 4gb? Should I include my data with the .apk? what about if I update the app? does the user have to redownload everything again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the apk file size that's been increased. However, I don't think it's a good idea to let your users download a 550+ MB apk file, as it'll take up a lot of internal storage and it's difficult to update when you have to download that massive file again.

Instead, create a smaller apk file that downloads the optional 500 MB data to the memory card. That way you can easily update the application and it's the most flexible for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

> But I just read that Google increased the app limit in the market to 4GB

Not yet. This was one of the items cited as being available in June 2011.

> Does that mean that you can host your data to the Android Market so that after your gets installed it downloads them from the Market?

Presumably, but there are few details at this time.

> Or does that mean that the max size of the .apk is 4gb? Should I include my data with the .apk? what about if I update the app? does the user have to redownload everything again?

I recommend that you wait until this exists and is documented before worrying. You can watch the [Google I|O presentation](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers#p/u/78/GxU8N21wfrM) where they announced this upcoming capability, to find out pretty much all we know on the subject.